# web programming: show overlay after DOM is loaded

Tags: overlay

How to show an overlay element after all things have been loaded on a web page? I don't know what to call this after "DOM" have been loaded? or document ready? please fill me in

i'm using the jquery plugins from this site:http://jquerytools.org/documentation/overlay/
the example on this site shows how to display an overlay but only after clicking something I want to know how to display immediately after all things have been loaded simply to make a login page with a login overlay.

thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

in `jquery` you can use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   //do what ever
});
```

or if you want you can use pure javascript like this

```
window.onload = function(e){ 
    //do something
}
```

they both do and mean the same thing. When the page elements are finished loading, like `divs` `span`, `p tags` and `text`.. do something..
this is needed because like in your case you have a div you want to show like an overlay, but if you don't wait until everything is loaded that div may not exist when your javascript wants to show it.

Comment: i've tried that but the "$("#id").overlay(); wont work. I should use .show(); instead? I want it to be displayed with fadein effects or something like that.

Comment: ya sure.. you can just use hide() and show()
you set the div style like you want it to be displayed and on load it show how you want it you don't need to hide it and show it again.. Then when you click on it you use $("#divid").click(function(){ this.hide() });